# Is it customary to include a dedication in an honours thesis?

Tags: thesis, dedication

I am compiling my thesis, and have noticed that the LaTeX template that I am using provides space for a dedication.

Whilst I do have an individual whom I want to credit with being a source of inspiration for my research and career motivation, I'm curious as to if honours theses normally include a dedication, and if I would be better to wait until I write my doctorate.

Comment: In my university, honors theses do normally include a dedication, the length can be varying from just a few sentences to up to a whole page.

Comment: It will unlikely cause a detriment to your grade, and it's a chance to recognise any assistance in a way that will be appreciated. In my thesis (physics, condensed matter), I made a special note of my advisor (for going above and beyond to keep me focused on a main goal, but also for allowing me many opportunities to delve into specific elements much further than was necessary to achieve the main goal - leading to my "further work" section being much more complete and informed) and some open source communities (particularly those behind key programming libraries) that made my work possible.

Comment: Besides the suggestions in answers: look at some recent previous honours theses from your department/university.  See what is commonly done by other students in your position.  If you check ten and none of them has a dedication?  Then probably don’t give one.  But if at least a few of them do, then you should be fine to give one.

Answer (score 11):

Dedication generally comes in your [front matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design#Front_matter) section in your thesis. It will depend on your university rules and guidelines. Generally "dedication" is **not mandatory** in most of universities. However it is advisable to check with your academic office.

Quoting from [Harvard](http://www.gov.harvard.edu/files/form_of_dissertation.pdf) guidelines for thesis writing,

> Front matter may include: acknowledgments of help or encouragement from individuals or institutions; a dedication; a list of illustrations or  of tables; a glossary of terms; one or more epigraphs—pertinent quotations at the beginning of a dissertation or a chapter

My personal opinion is that dedication gives emotional touch. It is good to have dedication page in your work.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I opted to include a dedication.

Comment: That is good :)

Answer (score 4):

To be absolutely sure, ask your advisor/supervisor – but they’ll probably advise that it is up to you, depending on the university’s guidelines.

Adding a dedication for, as you say, is a source of inspiration for your work, is a very kind and apt addition to your thesis. I agree with [Dexter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/56920/7734), that is a good thing to include.

I had dedication pages in my honours, masters and PhD theses, and these had no negative affect on the peer review that my work went through to be assessed (here, a thesis is peer-reviewed for assessment). One reviewer even noted that it was a “nice touch”.

Another to consider is that a “to the point” dedication for the inspiration for your work could garner positive exposure to the influential person’s work – which is also a very nice thing too.

But, when it comes down to it, it will be the academic content of your thesis that will truly matter.